# disabled text field issue with IE8, IE9, IE10

Tags: css

We have text field which is disabled. There is issue with text being BOLD in IE 10, but works fine with IE8, IE9.

```
input[type="text"][disabled], select:disabled, textarea:disabled{

background:#FFF !important;

text-shadow:0 !important;

box-shadow:none !important;

font-weight:bold !important;

}
```

for example in IE8, IE 9, even though i make Font weight as BOLD below is how it looks in disabled text field

Textfield: abcd

For IE10,
TextField: **adcb**

Please let me know how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: What font is on the input?

Comment: What is the problem? The second sentence says that it is a problem that the text is in bold. And you declare `font-weight: bold`. So the solution would be to remove that declaration. But are you saying that the problem is that it is *not* bold in some browsers?

Comment: yes it is not bold in IE8 and IE9

Comment: even if i make Font:normal, IE8, and IE9 won't display clear text when it is disabled with grey/white as background color. But IE10 there is no issue.